# Branching source to a different location TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2013, version-control, tfs, merge, branch

We have very large project and we have to branch some of the sources. Branched sources should be stored in a **different** location (within the same TFS server).
The problem is that due to active development of the main project we have to merge changes from trunk every day.
So the question is: how should I branch sources to provide the easiest merging from trunk.
The desired scenario is:
pull changes from trunk. Resolve conflicts and merge changed sources.
push merged changes to branch (that is stored in different location - not as a branched version in the same location)

Is this possible without any complex scripts?
I am using Visual Studio 2013 for work with TFS source control.

Answer (score 0):

You can have branch relationships been different locations in TFVC. You can branch from one team project to another and maintain the relationship.

If you currently have two locations that do not have a branch relationship you need to create one by doing a baseless merge first. One you have some a baseless merge you can then merge s normal As if they are in the same team project.

I would however recommend that you fix the problem that has lead to this situation. If you are going a single product then you should all be in the same team project.

http://nakedalm.com/one-team-project/